# C++ Draggable Borderless Form

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Alright, I'm making a simple sticky note application (Winodws Forms) **in C++** in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010. 
I'm trying to make a draggable borderless form.
The code I have now is:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
this->dragging = false;
}

private: System::Void Form1_MouseDown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
this->dragging = true;
this->offset = Point(e->X, e->Y);

}


private: System::Void Form1_MouseMove(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
if (this->dragging)
{
Point currentScreenPos = PointToScreen(e->Location);
Location = Point(currentScreenPos.X - this->offset.X, currentScreenPos.Y - this->offset.Y);
}

}

private: System::Void Form1_MouseUp(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
this->dragging = false;
}
```

This doesn't work for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are not using `e` in the MouseMove event.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than tracking the mouse manually, let the OS do it for you. Intercept the `WM_NCHITTEST` and return `HTCAPTION`. Or, using the MouseDown event only, send the window a special `WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_DRAG`message. There is plenty of info on MSDN about dragging borderless and/or captionless windows.

Comment: I'm only 13. I have no idea how to do what you just said.

Comment: Look up `WM_NCHITTEST` on MSDN. You can have your winform override it's virtual `WndProc()` method to catch the message. As for `SC_DRAG`, it is not officially documented, but it is `SC_MOVE + 2`. `SC_MOVE` is an available parameter of the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message, which you can send to your winform using the `SendMessage()` function.